# android google maps intent open location info

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Using the below, the intent will open a location in "Map" mode.  I am searching for the intent that will open the location in "Info" mode.  Map mode shows the location on the map, and if you click on the *MORE INFO* on the bottom, a view will show the location specific location detail.

Thanks in advance

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=Big Hoffa's Smokehouse, East Main Street, Westfield, IN");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```